# Can I add a second function export to module.exports without changing the way it's called?

Tags: node.js

I have a logging module that I use in many of my projects, which generally exports a single Winston logger, so all I did was define a logger and it's transports, then export it:

```
module.exports = logger;
```

when importing using `const logger = require('mylogger.js')` I then use the various levels built in (`logger.info logger.debug` etc).

I've now decided that I want to create a second logging function that will write logs to a different file, so I need to create and export a new transport. Thing is, if I switch to `module.exports = {logger, mynewlogger}`, that will change the way I import and call the functions, and I have that in many places.

Besides creating second file and importing both, is there any other way to add a second export without having to change my code everywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either new module that re-exports both:

*logger-and-mynewlogger.js*

```
module.exports = {logger, mynewlogger}
```

Or a separate module:

*mynewlogger.js*

```
module.exports = mynewlogger
```

Or using existing function as module object:

```
logger.mynewlogger = ...

module.exports = logger;
```

The first two options are preferable because they result in reasonably designed modules, while the last one is a quick and dirty fix.

Comment: Thanks. As I thought, I'll separate it, as I call the logger dozens of times

Comment: Whilst the above is perfectly valid, you can configure Winston to have multiple transports, so couldn't you create the additional transport in in Winston set-up and not have to change any code anywhere else?

Comment: @ChrisAdams can I generate a second transport and call it from the same exported function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define multiple transports for a single exported logger.  When creating your Winston log, the 'transports' property is an array which allows you to define multiple outputs.

Here's an example of one I have that has two transports.  Firstly, console and the second a daily rotating log.

```
const winston = require('winston');
const Rotate = require('winston-daily-rotate-file');    
const tsFormat = () => (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();

const logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        // colorize the output to the console
        new (winston.transports.Console)({
            timestamp: tsFormat,
            colorize: true,
            level: 'info',
        }),
        new (Rotate)({
            filename: `${logDir}/${logName}-app.log`,
            timestamp: tsFormat,
            datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
            prepend: true,
            level: env === 'development' ? 'verbose' : 'info',
        }),
    ],
});

module.exports = logger;
```